# How to build widget that depends on the value of Text Field?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add a Text widget in column and the value should be TextFormField's input value entered by the user.

**Code**

```
String text;
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 10, 30, 10),
      child: TextFormField(
        onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
          text= value;
        },
      ),
     Text(text), // want to add text here
   ]
```

It is throwing an error:

> **A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.**

What should be the good way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st make nullable text like  `String? text;`

Change based on Submit inside statefullWidget.

```
 onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
            setState(() {
              text = value;
            });
          },
```

Secondly, you need to handle null value like

`if (text != null) Text(text!),` or like `Text(text ?? "defaul value"),`

Widget will be like

```dart
 String? text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 10, 30, 10),
        child: TextFormField(
          onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
            setState(() {
              text = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      if (text != null) Text(text!), // want to add text here
    ]);
  }
```

does it solve in your case?

Comment: Yes. It works. Thanks. Can you explain this syntax Text(text!) ? I have used the other one.

Comment: `Text(text!)` means here `text!` won't be null, because we are using null safety and we have declared it as nullable value. It can receive null value, but `Text` widget don't take null value. Adding  bang `!` after text like `text!` we are saying that we have handled it, and it won't receive null value .

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not assigned any value while initializing the "String text" variable and the Text widget can not accept a null string, You may need to either initialize the text like this

```
String text = "";
```

or place or null check on the string in the text widget like this

```
Text(text??""),
```

or additionally, you can use null-safety like this

```
String? text;
```

Your final code will be like

```
String text = "";
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 10, 30, 10),
      child: TextFormField(
        onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
           setState((){
           text= value;
          });
        },
      ),
     Text(text??""), // placed null check
   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to https://github.com/lgjenero for the cool trick - update widgets depending on TextField state without `setState`.

```
  child: AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: _textEditController,
    builder: (context, child) {
      return Text(
        'Create',
        style: _textEditController.text.isEmpty ? styleOne : styleTwo,
      );
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code:

```
String? text;
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 10, 30, 10),
      child: TextFormField(
        onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
          text = value;
        },
      ),
     Text(text), // want to add text here
   ]
```